# Svelte 5 - Uncaught ReferenceError: $state is not defined

Tags: svelte, svelte-5

I am trying to make Svelte 5 project (I know it is still in alpha, but I want to play a bit with it), and I am using [this as a template for now](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/#H4sIAAAAAAAAE41U24rbMBD9FWEKTiDY725iKP2BwtJ9qfvg2JNUrSIZaZztYvTv1ciSLxvvUgIOo3M0Z2bOoCG5cAEmKX4MiaxvkBTJl65LDgm-dhSYOwgEFxvV64ZOjqbRvMOykhXyW6c0soG9cPz1TcP9iV9lLQyz7KLVjaVZHpHU8d2NRkmDrFFCaXZ6e22XXjWATPcjVwAyLrsen2vhyJ8M1gi7NMKXXjbIlWSmvsNuzwY6JAWXO2t6TQLx-ucRW2RLqSC0lTzmc0Py2JVUT8GGMU3nAnvMu9JDX13SCSKFCPm87MxlW9xr0cNpiEqW5UQ494iuUiWLRvDmz2mgmm355L7HfAQ3aaNUL1tly-_uuyBX0rlyUy2_cGiTAnUP9jCZGCc7O_nbLF2cndMc67OAA9NQt0qK18m80fvcoNLg7YO__tI0-Mk-Yuy45Mhr8UwDCG4Et0cvotKaONNo1kua6xouXEL71u--a2kRxj89G-9ksoDtKACJoZhTGUkVkkxmANeUiGrAXkcJvcWx-7A46x10CSW8LJuvMBbjC5jQrevk8LzCvsR4mYKNNny3pDrjb3uI89uoO1AWkyvm1Fnml_sQ47GSKXSiIeNhLreY1scXtA8Q9RVk7YcbFB6AjR2iVyBsUHgBHvaHKGF7AuX93VkNOuSlu3Mr7mA1Ovs4sGuoiTKxAPlccSQmEh52YtIgeGmmO4rk9XivobulmM9h3xny__4e34-f9h-2HM6GEAYAAA==)

My **App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { withPrevSignals } from './withPrev'

    const color = withPrevSignals('green')

    let inputVal = $state('')

    function save() {
        color.curr = inputVal;
        inputVal = ''
    }
</script>

<p>Prev: {color.prev}</p>
<p>Curr: {color.curr}</p>
<input bind:value={inputVal} />
<button on:click={save}>Save</button>
<button on:click={color.undo}>Undo</button>
```

**withPrev.js**

```
export function withPrevSignals(initialValue) {
    let curr = $state(initialValue)
    let prev = $state(undefined)

    function undo() {
        curr = prev
        prev = undefined
    }
    return {
        get curr() { return curr },
        set curr(newValue) {
            prev = curr
            curr = newValue
        },
        get prev() { return prev },
        undo
    }
}
```

I keep getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: $state is not defined both in the svelte 5 playground and on the local. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files using runes require the extension `.svelte.js` or `.svelte.ts` ([docs](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/docs/universal-reactivity)).

[Fixed REPL](https://svelte-5-preview.vercel.app/#H4sIAAAAAAAACo1U24rbMBD9FWEKTiDY725iKP2BwtJ9qfvgtZVUrSIJaZztYvTv1ejiS-JdSsBBOmfOXM6gMTszTk1W_Rgz0V5pVmVflMoOGbwpPJgb5UDd2chBd3hzNJ1mCupGNMCuSmogI3ll8OubprcndhEtN8SSs5ZXkhdlQoqglLswF9hJYYB0kktNTvfRu_yiKRX5PnA5BcKEGuC55Y78yUALdJcn-DyIDpgUxLQ3utuTES8xg9MuukFjghT-OWALtRwLAtuIYzn3JY6qxnoqMgYZ5Q72WKraQ1-d6ARhhgR5XfLCRF_dWj7Q05gyWVIi4WUAcJVKUXWcdX9OI9Zs6yf3PZYB3KSFVIPopa2_u--C3AhnzlX27Mxon1WgB2oPk5d30599_W2Wns4-agbtC6cHomnbS8HfJiuDQmlA6uAi_euDpvlPLiJjxwQD1vJnnEM0JZoeLEmZ1sSZhiNf0lzz9MwE7e9tH1SP-xD-9Oy_S1NEbIcHKiAWc6oTqQHlh0NhTUmopjDolEJvcew-7s96FZ2goK_L5htIxfgCJnQrHI2eN9mXmILxsNGG7xazzvh9D2l-G3VHymJy1SxdFH7HD-kcKpmOLmlUPMzlVtP6-IL2EcK-Ylr74QbFd2Bjh_AxiBsUH4KH_UFK3J5IeX93VoOOuhg7t-IuVqOzjwO7xJpQiUTIa6WRmER42IkpB8JLM91VIq_He4ndLZN5DfvOkP_39_iM_LT_AN8PW6IeBgAA)